# Can I automate changing my alarm on Snow Days?

Tags: macos, ios, automation, alarm

I use my iPhone to wake me up for school in the morning. The one flaw in that workflow is that, as any student knows, snow day season is very much upon us. I also have an iPad (school-given and limited accordingly) and an MBP. iOS 8.1.2 (non-jailbroken) and OS X 10.1.1.

I have a Mac and an iPhone and prefer the alarm be on the iPhone if possible.

I can subscribe to a notification service (such as one of the news stations that sends text or email notifications about school delays/closings) but don’t know how to chain that to have my alarms altered.

i.e. If my school calls a 2-hour delay, I want my 6:15 alarm turned off and an 8:15 one turned on, and if they call a full-blown cancellation, I want all alarms off. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [IFTTT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifttt/id660944635?mt=8), specifically the weather recipes, this isn't something the iPhone can do out-of-the-box. Jailbroken, i'm sure, but unless a developer specifically creates an app for you, this isn't something the iPhone has implemented into it's core services. [That's why the App Store Universe is so relevant and massive]. In regards to you turning an alarm off or on pending a No-School alert, isn't probable across any mediums I would think. You could code something a computer before implementing this on an iPhone or iPad.  Here's the thing, even if developers developed an app, they have no control over core services, so the alarm app that ships with the device is untouchable to any developer outside of apple, they can't turn that on or off, Apple won't let them. They can alter, change, update or create alarms or anything within their own app bundle, but nothing outside of it while maintain App Store Guidelines and integrity using Public APIs. So your resources are limited here. I'm not saying it's impossible, what I am saying, is you should probably focus your efforts towards a more robust (customizable) option like a computer (your MBP). The first step you have to over come is receive an alert like that and handle it

Comment: IFTTT works by sending trigger emails, right? If I set up Gmail to automatically forward emails from a notification service to IFTTT, what would the next steps be?

Comment: Well if your looking at it from that angle (recevie email from specific person then notify a recipe on IFTTT to activate) then you can just start looking through the [recipes](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?ac=false&page=1&q=gmail) and see if there is one already. I just did a quick glimpse and found a notification (I doubt its an alarm sound more of a notification sound since apple limits notification sounds to 30 sec, but maybe you can customize it in the app, I actually don't have it downloaded nor use it).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need an answer but I found something that should most definitely work. If you download the shortcuts app you can go onto the automations tab and click the little plus on the top right. After you down that if you scroll down a bit you can find two buttons that say email and message. If your school sends a email or text that school has been canceled then this should work. After you do that, configure that page how you need and make sure the bottom says run immediately. Then press next on the top right and click on “new blank automation”. After that click add action and then search “toggle alarm”. Pick the alarm you want of and set it to turn off. Hope this helps